# Typescript flatten complex nested array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm still pretty new to Typescript so I've been looking at all the provided solutions but I'm still stuck with a complex nested array. I have the following structure:

```
data = [{
    "property1_1": "value1_1",
    "property1_2": "value1_2",
    "property1_3": [
      [{
        "subproperty1_1_1": "subvalue1_1_1",
        "subproperty1_1_2": "subvalue1_1_2"
      }],
      [{
        "subproperty1_2_1": "subvalue1_2_1",
        "subproperty1_2_2": "subvalue1_2_2"
      }]
    ]
  },
  {
    "property2_1": "value2_1",
    "property2_2": "value2_2",
    "property2_3": [
      [{
        "subproperty2_2_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
        "subproperty2_2_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
      }],
      [{
        "subproperty2_2_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
        "subproperty2_2_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
      }]
    ]
  }
]
```

and I would like to achieve a simple array with objects looking like:

```
data = [{
    "property1_1": "value1_1",
    "property1_2": "value1_2",
    "subproperty1_1_1": "subvalue1_1_1",
    "subproperty1_1_2": "subvalue1_1_2",
    "subproperty1_2_1": "subvalue1_2_1",
    "subproperty1_2_2": "subvalue1_2_2"
  },
  {
    "property2_1": "value2_1",
    "property2_2": "value2_2",
    "subproperty2_1_1": "subvalue2_1_1",
    "subproperty2_1_2": "subvalue2_1_2",
    "subproperty2_2_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
    "subproperty2_2_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
  }
]
```

I've already achieved to collect the subproperties into one array like doing:

```
const allDataConv = [];
data.forEach(dateninput => {
  dateninput.propertyname.forEach(item => {
    item.forEach(lastitem => {
      allDataConv.push({key: lastitem.description, title: lastitem.name});
    });
  });
});
return allDataConv;
```

But that's not what I want to achieve. I'm stuck with the question: How can I apply the double nested objects into the corresponding parent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over your object keys and check if the value is an array. If it's an array use `flat(1)` to flatten it and then iterate over it's children. Use `Object.assign` to add the child object keys to your root object and delete the key which had the array as a value.

> `Array.flat` is an ESNext feature, you may need a polyfill for it in older browsers or use another for-of loop.

```js
const input = data = [
  {
    "property1_1": "value1_1",
    "property1_2": "value1_2",
    "property1_3": [
      [
        {
          "subproperty1_1_1": "subvalue1_1_1",
          "subproperty1_1_2": "subvalue1_1_2"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "subproperty1_2_1": "subvalue1_2_1",
          "subproperty1_2_2": "subvalue1_2_2"
        }
      ],
    ],
  },
  {
    "property2_1": "value2_1",
    "property2_2": "value2_2",
    "property2_3": [
      [
        {
          "subproperty2_1_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
          "subproperty2_1_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "subproperty2_2_1": "subvalue2_2_1",
          "subproperty2_2_2": "subvalue2_2_2"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
];

function transformData(input) {
  return input.map(obj => {
    for(const prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
        for(const subObj of obj[prop].flat(1)) {
          Object.assign(obj, subObj);
          delete obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  })
}

console.log(transformData(input));
```